# Grouping 12V ATX lines for measurements

Tags: current-measurement, atx

I'd like to measure the power draw of my CPU. The way that seems the most straightforward to me is to cut into the ATX12V cable and put a shunt based sensor in the middle of the 12V line. Now in the 4 pin cable there are two of them and I assume they are wired in parallel to divide the current and still keep the overall cabling flexible. Naturally I'd cut both and wire up together and the terminals of my sensor.

Is there any non obvious downside or danger in that that would force me to install a current sensor on the each wire instead?

Apologies in advance for silly question, just making sure I don't miss anything.

Comment: Not an answer but why not use a "amp clamp" style meter?

Comment: A clamp-on ammeter is the obvious solution. Note that you need one that can specifically cope with DC measurements; the default is to only work on AC.